# How to Read Txt File to a Webpage TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html

I am trying to read a txt file content (file location will be specified by user) into a asp.net webpage textbox. The webpage will be deployed on a server

The most import part is to track the full path of the txt file selected by user

How can I do that by using vb code or other code if possible?

Comment: I know how to read the txt content by using StreamReader(fullfilePath), but how can I get the file path that user selected? The FileUpload control or Html input(File) can let user select the txt file. However the browser won't let you get the full file path by using these two controls.

Comment: You're not going to get access to the full path via the FileUpload control because of security restrictions. You'll have to make do with filename. Why is it important that you track the full path ? If you could explain a bit more maybe we can come up with an alternative.

Comment: My main goal is to read a txt file content specified by user to a textbox.  I know the StreamReader(filename) can read the txt file, but I don't know how to find the txt file that user selected? If you could give me some suggestion on how to find the filename. :) Thanks

Comment: You cannot do this. All modern browsers will remove the full path for security reasons. IE can be tricked into doing it but no other browser can IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need InputStream to get the text data from a text file

```
 var fileStream = new StreamReader(fileuplodID.PostedFile.InputStream);
        string Data = fileStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: This does *NOT* give you the full path to the filename, so why are you saying "this one works" ?